# Generate a consistent sha256 hash from an object in Node

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, sha256

I have an object that I'd like to hash with sha256 in Node. The contents of the object are simple Javascript types. For example's sake, let's say:

```
var payload = {
    "id": "3bab3f00-7d55-11e7-9b0a-4c32759242a5",
    "foo": "a message",
    "version": 7,
};
```

I create a hash like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update( ... ).digest('hex');
```

The question is, what to pass to update? The [documentation for crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding) says you can pass a `<string> | <Buffer> | <TypedArray> | <DataView>`, which seems to suggest an object is not a good thing to pass.

I can't use `toString()` because that prints `"[object Object]"`. I could use JSON.stringify, however I have read elsewhere that the output from stringify is not guaranteed to be deterministic for the same input.

Are there any other options? I do not want to download a package from NPM.

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this? That might provide dtter ideas of how.

Comment: I guess the same reason anyone wants to hash anything... to create a repeatable digest of the object contents that's a) distinct from hashes of objects that differ and b) hard to forge

Comment: So this is one of several npm modules I found after a simple Google search. If they don't meet you need they might give ideas.  https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/blob/master/readme.markdown

Comment: Why don't you want to download something from npm?

Comment: https://github.com/mirkokiefer/canonical-json

Answer (score 4):

The right terms are "canonical" and the action is called "canonicalization" (I'm assuming EN-US here), you can find a stringify that produces canonical output [here](https://github.com/mirkokiefer/canonical-json).

Beware that you must make sure that the output also has the right character set (UTF-8 should be preferred) and line endings. Spurious data should not be present, e.g. a byte order mark or NUL termination string is enough to void the hash value.

After that you can pass it as `string` I suppose.

---

You can of course use any canonical encoding. Note that XML has defined XML-digsig, which contains canonicalization *during signature generation and signing*, which means that the verification will even succeed if the XML code is altered (without altering the structure or contents of course, but whitespace / indentation will not matter).

---

I'd still recommend regression testing between implementations and even version updates of the libraries.

Comment: Note that JavaScript and JSON were created for easy usage, not for strictness. Unfortunately, security and cryptography require strictness. Hence you will require more testing to create a secure implementation. I'm not saying that this is good or bad, just that it **is**.